# Django - Inserting rows at each migration

Tags: django, database

I am making a wesbsite with the Django framework.

I have a model for contact informations which looks like :

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_info = models.CharField(max_length=100) # e.g. 'Phone number'
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100) # e.g '0123456789'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_info
```

This model would only contain a few rows : 1 for the phone number, 1 for the mailing adress, 1 for GPS coordinates ...

Is there a way to tell Django to insert those rows at each migration if they are not already in the table ? It would be for easing the deployment of the website.

Comment: Have you read about [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) or the  [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found out what i was looking for :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

and

http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupinitialdatadjangomodels.html